# PostgreSQL query on text array value

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table where one column has an array - but stored in a text format:

```
mytable

id  ids
--  -------
1   '[3,4]'
2   '[3,5]'
3   '[3]'
etc ...
```

I want to find all records that have the value 5 as an array element in the `ids` column.

I was trying to achieve this by using the "string to array" function and removing the `[` symbols with the `translate` function, but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5c148/12

```
select *
from tbl
where translate(ids, '[]','{}')::int[] && array[5];
```

Output:

```
| ID |   IDS |
--------------
|  2 | [3,5] |
```

---

You can also use bool_or: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5c148/11

```
with a as
(
  select id, unnest(translate(ids, '[]','{}')::int[]) as elem
  from tbl
)
select id
from a
group by id
having bool_or(elem = 5);
```

To see the original elements:

```
with a as
(
  select id, unnest(translate(ids, '[]','{}')::int[]) as elem
  from tbl
)
select id, '[' || array_to_string(array_agg(elem), ',') || ']' as ids
from a
group by id
having bool_or(elem = 5);
```

Output:

```
| ID |   IDS |
--------------
|  2 | [3,5] |
```

---

Postgresql DDL is atomic, if it's not late yet in your project, just structure your stringly-typed array to a real array: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6e18c/2

```
alter table tbl
add column id_array int[];

update tbl set id_array = translate(ids,'[]','{}')::int[];

alter table tbl drop column ids;
```

Query:

```
select *
from tbl
where id_array && array[5]
```

Output:

```
| ID | ID_ARRAY |
-----------------
|  2 |      3,5 |
```

You can also use contains operator: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6e18c/6

```
select *
from tbl
where id_array @> array[5];
```

I prefer the `&&` syntax though, it directly connotes intersection. It reflects that you are detecting if there's an intersection between two sets(array is a set)

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, its actually not that late, i will try to convince that this field gets changed to a real array, thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3):

If you store the string representation of your arrays slightly differently, you can cast to `array of integer` directly:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES 
 (1, '{3,4}')
,(2, '{3,5}')
,(3, '{3}');

SELECT id, ids::int[]
FROM   mytable;
```

Else, you have to put in one more step:

```
SELECT (translate(ids, '[]','{}'))::int[]
FROM   mytable
```

I would consider making the column an array type to begin with.

Either way, you can find your row like this:

```
SELECT id, ids 
FROM  (
    SELECT id, ids, unnest(ids::int[]) AS elem
    FROM   mytable
    ) x
WHERE  elem = 5
```

Comment: agreed, though if he can edit the database structure he would be better off storing those IDs in separate fields entirely.

Comment: @sudowned: Or even in a separate table with one number per row. But we really don't have enough information to tell for sure.